# Why doesn't Simplify[Sqrt[(Sin[a])^2] ] give Sin[a]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am getting `Sqrt[Sin[a]^2]` as the output to a calculation and I want it to be displayed as `Sin[a]`.

Comment: (1) `Sqrt[sin^2(a)]` is not proper syntax. (2) `Sqrt[u^2]` does not equal `u`, even for the real numbers, much less for complex numbers, which is the domain *Mathematica* works over.  You could try `Simplify[Sqrt[(sin (a))^2], sin (a) > 0]`, which yields `a sin`, an equivalent form of `sin(a)`, according to *Mathematica* syntax.  Probably you want `Simplify[Sqrt[Sin[a]^2], Sin[a] > 0]` and to learn the syntax of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked that. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `PowerExpand` to do this simplification, but you should be sure that this is the right thing to do (see @JohnDoty's answer).

Answer (score 4):

Well, proper syntax would help. Then note that

```
Sqrt[Sin[a]^2] /. a -> -I
(* I Sinh[1] *)
```

but

```
Sin[a] /. a -> -I
(* -I Sinh[1] *)
```

Comment: I see. 
I'm not familiar with the syntax
 /. a -> -I
What does it mean?

Comment: Look up `Replace` in the documentation.

Comment: @AdwaitMane There's a compendium for such symbols [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to get the desired form by restricting a to the reals. Simplify[Sqrt[(Sin[a])^2], -Infinity < a < Infinity] gives |Sin[a]|.